# What is the best way to attach javadoc to my SpringBoot application in STS?

Tags: spring, eclipse, javadoc, spring-tool-suite

Using Spring Boot in my application:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

It appears that javadoc is not bundled with these libraries (this maven was auto-generated by Spring Tool Suite upon creating a Spring Boot project) and I tried it adding it manually. This creates a couple of issues:

1) There are a lot of Spring libraries in the typical project: spring-boot-starter-aop, spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE, etc, and adding the javadoc location 1-by-1 would be tedious.

2) Even when I try adding the java at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/ I find that I get an error parsing this URL: "*unknown javadoc format for SpringApplication...*"

Is there an easier way to get Spring Javadoc in my STS environment?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but usually the Maven integration in STS/Eclipse downloads sources for Maven dependencies automatically, so that you can dive into the source code of the libs directly from your code. This also results in javadoc of the libs being rendered and shown in the views in STS/Eclipse as well as content-assist. Would that help?

Comment: No, it does not happen automatically unless you set it to do so in the preferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Maven you can download the associated Javadoc from the corresponding contextual menu entry, right-click on the project tree and then go to Maven -> Download JavaDoc

[image: Dropdown menu]

If you want Maven to download the associated javadoc by default you can select the corresponding option from the STS preferences dialog under Maven -> Download Artifact JavaDoc

[image: Preferences dialog]